# Libsodium secretbox_open_easy can't decrypt contents from a file

Tags: c, encryption, libsodium

I have been trying to make my own file encryption/decryption program in C using libsodium and I have been having some trouble with decrypting contents from a file that was encrypted. I have been able to establish a key that stays the same whenever you put in the same password using key derivation with the same salt, nonce and options for the crypto_pwhash function. When I encrypt it's fine, but when I go to decrypt with the same key it fails and I can't get a good output on what is failing in the function.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sodium.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int getLength(FILE *filePointer);
int getFileData(const char *filename, char **dataBuffer);
void writeFileData(const char *newFileName, const char *data, const int dataLen);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    
    char *filename = "file.txt.enc";
    char *contents = NULL;
    int contentLength;

    contentLength = getFileData(filename, &contents);
    printf("%s\n", contents);

    // printf("%s\n", contents);

    char *password = "Passw0rd!";
    unsigned char salt[8] = "$6$/Fge\0";
    unsigned char key[32];

    if (crypto_pwhash(key, 32, password, strlen(password), salt, 64000, 64000, crypto_pwhash_ALG_ARGON2I13) != 0){
        perror("[ERROR]");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n", key);
    unsigned char nonce[14] = "?5oiRyait$Kn\0";
    
    -[snip]-
 
    else if (strncmp(argv[1], "-d", 2) == 0){
        printf("[INFO] In Decryption\n");
        unsigned char decrypted[64] = { 0 };
        if (crypto_secretbox_open_easy(decrypted, contents, contentLength, nonce, key) != 0){
            printf("%s\n", decrypted);
            perror("[FAILED]");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("%s\n", decrypted);
    }

    else{
        printf("[ERROR] Not a known option. Use '-e/-d filename'\n");
        return -1;
    }


    return 0;
```

Is there anything wrong I'm passing to the secretbox_open_easy function? **EDIT** When it doesn't work and hits the `perror`, all it says is `[FAILED]: Success`

Comment: `contentLength = strlen(contents);` Do you expect that your encrypted content is a nul-terminated string? Do you use base64 encoding or similar? Do you add that 0-byte in your `getFileData` function or is it stored in the file?

Comment: `unsigned char salt[7] = "$6$/Fge";` one too few chars here, that needs to be `[8]` for the `NUL` terminator... or initialize it as a character array (instead of a string) if that's the intent.

Comment: @Gerhardh If I am able to output `contents` to terminal, does that mean its already a null-terminated string? I use fread to get the contents of the file but I don't know it that adds a '\0' to the string when I return it to the `contents` variable

Comment: @yano When you use libsodium's randombuf or other key generation functions, are they automatically null-terminated strings?

Comment: also @Gerhardh, When should I use the base64 encoding? right before I put the encrypted text into the file?

Comment: I have no clue about libsodium. What I do know about is C, and when you initialize a character array with double quotes, that's interpreted as a string, and a `NUL` terminator is automatically added, so you need to account for that in your size declaration (or better yet, just omit the size declaration and the compiler will deduce the size automatically). You're overrunning your array by only declaring it with 7 spaces (it needs 8), and that invokes undefined behavior. Not saying correcting that will fix all your problems, but it is something that must be corrected.

Comment: actually, I'm quite dumbfounded gcc doesn't produce a warning [on this](https://godbolt.org/z/sjEa16v3W), but if you [add the `-fsanitize=address` option](https://godbolt.org/z/xfdYG6Gxf), it does complain. You can [fix it](https://godbolt.org/z/K6o5jax79) by doing `unsigned char salt[8] = "$6$/Fge";` or `unsigned char salt[] = "$6$/Fge";`.

Comment: Printing `content` to terminal can indicate that just by accident the data was nul-terminated. But can you really be sure that you don't get some extra characters? Maybe even non-printable ones? `fread` will not add any termination to any data read. It reads binary data, not text and hence does not care about nul-termination.

Comment: When you encrypt some data I would expect to get some result that does not necessarily represent a valid C string or that contains only readable characters etc. But you treat it as a string and I am wonderng how this seems to work.

Comment: @Gerhardh I should've been more clear about the outputs I'm getting. When I output the key to the console it looks something like `�T,���4�)Ny�V` and thats the same output I'm getting whether I run the program while encrypting or decrypting. The output to the encrypted file on the other hand will look like `ÁŸùvŒ.^9ðŸú...` when I'm looking at it with an my IDE. So is it that the secretbox_open_easy functions wants to see a NULL terminated string instead of just the bytes?

Comment: @yano thank you for the C tips, I come from python and I'm still new to C so I keep forgetting about how import the NULL character is.

Comment: I don't think, `secretbox_open_easy` expects a string. But you are using `strlen` to determine the length of your data. That will cut anything that follows after a 0 byte if there is one in your file.

Comment: Regarding your output: You should only view such data with a hex viewer or as hex dump. Printing binaray data will only produce garbage,

Comment: So I changed how I get the length by using `fseek` and `ftell` but I can't seem to find out whats still wrong while I'm decrypting?